# How to make compatible an android app for multiple screen (Different size and different resolutions)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-widget, android-resources

I am developing an Android application in **portrait view only**. This is working fine for 320 * 480 resolutions in all android versions (Version 2.2 to 4.2).

Now I want to support this application for the following resolution too:

1. 960x540
2. 480x800
3. 1280x720

What will be the best approach to support my application for multiple screens.

I have 3 types of images: 1x, 1.5x and 2x.

In 320 * 480 resolutions I am using 1x images.

I searched a lot but still not clear what approach will be **the best and right approach.**

I have few options:

1. Use a **single layout** (under res/layout) and **separate drawables** (under res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi and res/drawable-xhdpi) for each resolution.
2. Using **separate layouts** (under res/layout, res/layout-large and res/layout-xlarge) and **separate drawables** (under res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi and res/drawable-xhdpi.) for each resolution.

Or any other best approach which should be always used whenever support multiple screens.

Onr more problem: When I am using any one above approach, **my changes are not appear on hdpi and xhdpi screens.**

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here are the Android docs on that](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single right way, I believe this decision depends of your application.

In apps with clean layouts, I make an unique xml_layout, and I use [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) to distribute the elements on the screen. Thereby, I get a similar distribution of this elements on the space available, in the all different screen resolutions.

Otherwise, when the layout is more complex, it's necessary to create different layouts to support the different screens.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is 2, and it is the Android standard, recommended way of providing resources.
And I think your problem is due to you did not specify the correct type. For layout alternatives, you can also use:

layout-h720dp

layout-land

layout-sw600dp

layout-sw600dp-land

layout-sw720dp

layout-w720dp

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Thanks Robin. Can you please suggest me what layout folder names should I used for the my above resolutions? Beacuse I am still unclear when name should be used? When I use layout-large and layout-xlarge or when I use layout-w720dp ?

Comment: I think you should consider your layout against DPI, not resolution. Please go to Android dev site to get clear understanding of these 2 different concept.